# Using JUnit is there as way to unit test POJOs that implement getters and setters using lombok?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, lombok

I am using SpringBoot, Maven, and the Surfire plugin.

For example, if I have a POJO such as :

```
@Data public class Foo{ private String str1 ;  private String str2}
```

Is it possible to write a test using JUnit to similar to

```
   public class FooTest{
       @Test testMethod(){
           Foo foo = new Foo() ;
           foo.setStr1("STRING") ;
           assertThat(foo.getStr1(), instanceOf(String.class)) ;
           assertEquals(foo.getStr1(),"STRING") ;
       }
   }
```

I have been looking all over the Net for a solution.

Apparently the problem seems to be that JUnit cannot find Foo's getter and setter methods in order to run any tests against them because they don't exist until Lombok creates them at runtime.   Is there a work around for this ?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated !!!!

Comment: What is that test method supposed to test?

Comment: @Tom  I edited the  code.  Basically this is all I am trying to do.   When I run the test it failes because it doesn't know what "foo.setStr1()"  nor  "foo.getStr1()"  are.

Comment: Then the test isn't the issue here, it more looks like Lombok isn't configured correctly and the post processors aren't running or your IDE isn't able to work with Lombok and just thinks those methods are missing. Does Lombok work in the production code? How are you running those tests? Any difference between running then in the IDE or using a console?

Comment: I am running the tests from the command line:   mvn  -Dtest=FooTest test

Comment: Lombok annotated Pojos are running in production

Comment: *"because they don't exist until Lombok creates them at runtime."* ... This shouldn't be the case. Lombok uses a post processor which generates the necessary code into the `.class` files, thus when you look into your `build` dir, then your built classes don't have any Lombok trace in there (except maybe a marker that a method was generated using Lombok). That's also why you configure your Lombok dependency as "provided" in the pom file. And all that is why I'm surprised that the production code works, but Junit doesn't.